# How do I solve "libmagic" import error in Azure Container App

Tags: django, linux, azure, azure-container-apps, libmagic

$ `python3 manage.py migrate`
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
`File "/app/manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 20, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/core/event/models.py", line 15, in <module>
    from versatileimagefield.fields import VersatileImageField
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/versatileimagefield/fields.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .files import VersatileImageFieldFile, VersatileImageFileDescriptor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/versatileimagefield/files.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .mixins import VersatileImageMixIn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/versatileimagefield/mixins.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .datastructures import FilterLibrary
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/versatileimagefield/datastructures/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .sizedimage import SizedImage
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/versatileimagefield/datastructures/sizedimage.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..utils import get_resized_path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/versatileimagefield/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import magic
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/magic/__init__.py", line 209, in <module>
    libmagic = loader.load_lib()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/magic/loader.py", line 49, in load_lib
    raise ImportError('failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation')
ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation`
```

I am trying to run `python3 manage.py migrate` to create my schema in Azure Postgresql DB

I have tried adding the following to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update &&\
     apt-get install -y libmagic1
```

but I'm still getting the same error when I run the `migrate` function on the container console